# How to move the cursor to the particullar paragraph using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word?

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, ms-office

We are developing `C#.Net 4.0` Windows form based application using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` reference.

Now I want to move the position of the cursor to the particular paragraph.

How I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
void MoveToParagraph(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document d, int number)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range r = d.Paragraphs[number].Range;
    object dir = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseStart;

    r.Collapse(ref dir);
    r.Select();
}
```